# Assemble multiple String into one

Tags: java, string, bluetooth

I work on a Bluetooth application and I receive my data in several String packages. (I use speed Baud 9600)

example:

```
02-19 09:44:59.516 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: [1/1/0 
02-19 09:44:59.516 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: 0:12:32]
02-19 09:44:59.526 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER:  Timesta
02-19 09:44:59.536 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: mp=94668
02-19 09:44:59.546 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: 5552 ID=
02-19 09:44:59.556 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: 40 Value
02-19 09:44:59.566 12659-12659/com.example.appcopeeks I/RECEIVER: =2453
```

here is a video of what I get [screenpresso.com/=8kakb](http://screenpresso.com/=8kakb) 
I would like to put all this together in a string.

example:

```
[11/2/19 9:48:25] Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475
```

I tried this but it did not work.

```
 public class CapteurActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private StringBuilder dataFull = new StringBuilder();
 ...
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            switch (intent.getAction()){
                //writes the data received in the EditText
                case BGXpressService.BGX_DATA_RECEIVED: {
                    String stringReceived = intent.getStringExtra("data");

                    if ( stringReceived != null ) {
                        if ( stringReceived.startsWith("[")) {
                            getAssembleData(intent);
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d("Test DataFull: ",dataFull.toString());

        ...
  }
 }
}
     ...
public String getAssembleData(Intent intent){
    StringBuilder dataFull = new StringBuilder();
    String stringReceived = intent.getStringExtra("data");

    while (!stringReceived.contains("[")){
        dataFull.append(stringReceived);
    }
    return dataFull.toString();
 }
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read.

Comment: Try declaring `StringBuilder dataFull` as a class member.

Comment: it did not change my problem :/

Comment: Well, sorry. you know i tried, realy did ;) But doesn't seem to realy getting somewhere. So please provide an example, that is actually reproducible, so it becomes possible to give you a straight answer with something that works. thx

Comment: I have several string and I would like him to form one. 
The string I receive this nome stringReceived. 
here is a video of what I get https://screenpresso.com/=8kakb

Comment: For the NPE  I can say so much "intent.getStringExtra("data");" returns null. but I have no way of telling what this method does or where else the null comes from. ;)

Comment: let's skip this problem that I'll settle later. Let's imagine that it never returns null

Comment: getAssembleData() is the new toAssemble()
I forgot to edit

Comment: than I can say so much, that you have an endless loop in the while(which should eventually fail as buffer exceeds memory) - alternatively it is never executed.

Comment: Maybe that helps: you are only working with one single value. So there are not multiple values to collect atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call toAssemble twice and you don't check for Null Pointer Exception. Here is a more simple approach which could fit your needs.
lastStringReceived will have the last String assembly stored till a new String is received.

```java
 public class CapteurActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static String lastStringReceived = "";
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
 ...
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

            switch (intent.getAction()){
                //writes the data received in the EditText
                case BGXpressService.BGX_DATA_RECEIVED: {
                    String stringReceived = intent.getStringExtra("data");
                    if ( stringReceived != null ) {
                        if ( stringReceived.startsWith("[")) {
                            lastStringReceived = buffer.toString();
                            buffer = new StringBuffer();
                        }
                        buffer.append(stringReceived)
                    }

        ...
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: right -  but I think in this case the op should have a look at why it is null instead of ignoring it.

Comment: well, he's calling toAssemble() twice

Comment: I have just corrected my code. 
but I still do not have the result to hope for.

Comment: Maybe the adaption works for you. Build the String directly and save it somewhere when a new String starts

Comment: sorry,  but now your code seems to have some issues: it has no loop, so you have at most one String. So lastStringreceived is allways "" and buffer may or may not hold a single String.

Comment: actually lastStringReceived always remains empty.

Comment: Moved the lastStringReceived to a static in the class. Loop should not be necessary as the onReceive method should be called whenever something is sent, or I'm mistaken?
Or is the onReceive method called once and there are multiple messages in the intent's data attribute? - not clear in the code example

If it's last, you can go with a simple split, if it's first my code is valid

Comment: still the same its allways "".

Comment: Have you checked with the debugger?  Maybe the `intent.getStringExtra("data")` does not start with `"["`?

Comment: if it starts well with "[" then it creates an endless loop :/
and I do not see how to manage to select the part I want...                                                  
  [11/2/19 9:48:25] Timestamp=1549878505 ID=4 Value=2475

Comment: @MaximilianVoss: I checked with my eyes, "lastStringReceived = buffer.toString();" and buffer is empty as of StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); //qed

Comment: In this case, move the StringBuffer also outside, then it should be filled